# Passing values of a select option in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I am trying to pass in the value of the selected option to my ng change function. Shown below is my code

```
 <select ng-model="this.value" ng-change="showExecutionStepOptions(study.id,acase.id,this.value)">
                                        <option value='acase.executionSteps[0].id' selected=selected>TOPPER</option>
                                        <option value='acase.executionSteps[1].id'>RSC</option>
                                        <option value='acase.executionSteps[2].id'>SPD</option>
                                        <option value='acase.executionSteps[3].id'>SFT</option>
                                        <option value='acase.executionSteps[4].id'>LMP</option>
                                     </select>
```

Can someone please tell me what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: No jsfiddle, no plunker? It could help.. Did you know what the "this" keyword refer to? I don't think so, and that's really not the problem. Avoid to use this in a view, it would be easyer for you. You can try to replace your ng-model with that: ng-model="test", and use "test" in your ng-change instead of this.value? If you want to generate a select the angular way, take a look on ng-options.

Comment: ng-model is actually test as ng-model="test". But I think my whole syntax is not correct

Comment: can you please at least add model for acase ?

Comment: case has a list of execution steps. Each execution step has an id. Which is what I am trying to select and pass in my ng-change function, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: http://jsbin.com/xoyuf/1/

HTML:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.acases = [
   {id:1, value:"TOPPER"},
   {id:2, value:"RSC"},
   {id:3, value:"SPD"},
   {id:4, value:"SFT"},
   {id:5, value:"LMP"},
 ];
});
```

Comment: Problem is my acases are being populated on the client HTML side. All examples of select show the options being populated from the JS side. The values that I need to pass in the options come from the HTML side

Comment: @user3799365  I'm not sure what you means by populated by HTML side but maybe that will help http://jsbin.com/xoyuf/3/edit

Comment: So what if I want to be able to access the value of the selected option in the controller. From your example shouldn't I be able to do a $scope.selected. For me it shows up as undefined, I appreciate your answers, can you please explain why cannot I access the selected option in the controller using $scope.selected in the example you provided

Comment: @user3799365 `selected=selected` is not going to work if you want predefine selected value in your view you can do that this way : http://jsbin.com/xoyuf/4/ <select ng-init="selected=0" ....

Comment: For your controller 
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
console.log($scope.selected);
}); I want to be able to print the value of selected

Comment: My question is I want to be able to access the ng-model=selected's value and pass it to a function defined as ng-change="operateOnOptions(selected)", and then inside my controller I have $scope.operationOnOptions = function(selected){...} So how do I pass the value of the selected to the controller, I am not worried about having a pre-defined selected value.

Comment: Thanks for all your time, I do the same exact thing you are doing. I can see your example is working too but when I print out I get a Object {$$hashKey: "00S"} instead of the value

Comment: @user3799365 can you please add you code to jsbin as otherwise is difficult to help

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wukimoxo/1/edit, I added my code there, once again thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes you made, I don't see any difference but your code works.

Comment: @user3799365 please click on tab javascript you missed completely all angular controller and app.module definition bit, and in your html you need to add ng-app and ng-controller as well

Comment: I have all that in my main application, I was just showing you the code to see why it doesn't work. For some reason on my main application, this "selected" will not work. I sincerely appreciate all your time.

Comment: @user3799365 I've just added those things to your solution and everything is fine http://jsbin.com/wukimoxo/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the selected option so you need to pass option name in value like this

```
 <select ng-model="this.value" ng-change="showExecutionStepOptions(this.value)">
                                        <option value='TOPPER'>TOPPER</option>
                                        <option value='RSC'>RSC</option>
                                        <option value='SPD'>SPD</option>
                                        <option value='SFT'>SFT</option>
                                        <option value='LMP'>LMP</option>
                                     </select>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <select ng-model="this.value" ng-change="showExecutionStepOptions(this.value)">
                                        <option value='TOPPER'>TOPPER</option>
                                        <option value='RSC'>RSC</option>
                                        <option value='SPD'>SPD</option>
                                        <option value='SFT'>SFT</option>
                                        <option value='LMP'>LMP</option>
                                     </select>
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{this.value}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help for you